# Table with rounded border using CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue. I have a table made with pure HTML code, here is it:

```
<table id="calendarTable">
  <tr>
    <th id="tableHeader" colspan=7></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Dom</th>
    <th>Seg</th>
    <th>Ter</th>
    <th>Qua</th>
    <th>Qui</th>
    <th>Sex</th>
    <th>Sáb</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="tableBody"></tbody>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=7>
    <p>
      <form id="dateChooser" name="dateChooser">
        <select name="chooseMonth" onChange="populateTable(this.form)">
          <option selected>Janeiro
          <option>Fevereiro
          <option>Março
          <option>Abril
          <option>Maio
          <option>Junho
          <option>Julho
          <option>Agosto
          <option>Setembro
          <option>Outubro
          <option>Novembro
          <option>Dezembro
        </select>
        <select name="chooseYear" onChange="populateTable(this.form)">
        </select>
      </form>
    </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#calendarTable {
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #18B6E6;
  border-color: #18B6E6;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#calendarTable td {
  border: solid 1px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#calendarTable th {
  border: solid 1px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

I want to round the borders using only CSS, I just tried using the border-radius property but my table is not changing borders.

Anyone have a tip for me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include your CSS.

Comment: My CSS is not relevant, I just made a color to my text and borders.

Comment: Of course it's relevant.  The problem could very well be in your CSS!

Comment: `border-radius` can’t be used on `tr`, try it on `td`.

Comment: I don't see `border-radius` in your CSS.  Are you trying to apply it to the whole table, or to every single cell?  I ask because I don't see `border-collapse` in your CSS.

Comment: to my whole table.. what border-collapse can do here?

Comment: @daniel_serretti Well, if you were using border-collapse, that would basically make `border-radius` meaningless for individual cells.  See the demo in @user3127499's answer, and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, this is the code that should give the look you want.

### Code

```css
#RoundedTable {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#RoundedTable td, #RoundedTable th {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<table id="RoundedTable">
  <tr><th>Table header</th><th>Another header cell</th></tr>
  <tr><td>Table cell...</td><td>More data...</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Table cell...</td><td>More data...</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Table cell...</td><td>More data...</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Table cell...</td><td>More data...</td></tr>
</table>
```

### Caveat

For this to work, though, you need to make sure that `border-collapse` is set to `separate` instead of `collapse` for your table.  Otherwise, neither the radius for the cells nor the radius for the whole table will work.

So look through the other CSS that may be affecting your table.  If you find `border-collapse: collapse;` anywhere, that's the problem.

Comment: That's exactly my problem. As I am using bootstrap too, it have a property for table that set border-collapse: collapse for all tables.. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Here's a simplified table with border radius applied. The trick is to set the left border of the cell rather than the table itself. It'll work with or without a `thead` and I've annotated the `css` to show what I'm doing.

```css
/*
 * First normalise some of the attributes
 */

table td,
table th {
  padding: .5rem;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}
/*
 * Add the border, set border spacing etc
 * The left width is 0 so cell border can be applied without doubling up.
 */

.table-bordered {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}
/*
 * Add the border to table cell/header
 */

.table-bordered td,
.table-bordered th {
  border-top: 1px solid silver;
  border-left: 1px solid silver;
}
/*
 * Remove the top border from the first header/cell
 */

.table-bordered tbody:first-child tr:first-child td,
.table-bordered thead:first-child tr:first-child th {
  border-top-width: 0;
}
/*
 * Set the border radius for the first header/cell
 */

.table-bordered thead:first-child tr:first-child td:first-child,
.table-bordered thead:first-child tr:first-child th:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 1rem;
}
/*
 * Set the border radius for the last header/cell
 */

.table-bordered tbody:last-child tr:last-child td:first-child,
.table-bordered tbody:last-child tr:last-child th:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Data</th>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Data</th>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Data</th>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This should be the top answer. Good job :)

Answer (score 2):

```
#calendarTable{

    border-radius:20px;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6kr2dzff/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the border attribute on the table. It is still supported in browsers, but it is [removed from HTML5 specification](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp). The effect that attribute makes is probably not what you want anyways.

If you want border around each cell in your table just specify that in CSS and include border-radius there as well.

I.e.

```
#calendarTable td { border: solid 1px; border-radius: 4px; }
```

If you just want border around the whole table, use the same css on table selector:

```
#calendarTable { border: solid 1px; border-radius: 4px; }
```

Comment: I just tried it, I removed the border attribute and added these two new properties to my #calendarTable, but is still not working... The borders don't change.

Answer (score 2):

`border-radius` seems to work both on `table` and `td` elements, with or without the `border` attribute on `table`.

You must have some other CSS rules coming into play.

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
table td, table th {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>Table header...</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Table cell...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Table cell...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Table cell...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Table cell...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yeah! That's what I want, thank you. I will take a look if there are other CSS properties doing something here..

Comment: was the border-collapse set to collapse coming from bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

based [on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29683421/2139007) as tailwind:

```css
.table-bordered {
    @apply w-full border-separate border-spacing-0 overflow-clip rounded-lg border border-l-0;
}

.table-bordered td,
.table-bordered th {
    @apply border-l border-t text-left align-top;
}

.table-bordered tbody:first-child tr:first-child td,
.table-bordered thead:first-child tr:first-child th {
    @apply border-t-0;
}

.table-bordered thead:first-child tr:first-child td:first-child,
.table-bordered thead:first-child tr:first-child th:first-child {
    @apply rounded-tl-lg;
}

.table-bordered tbody:last-child tr:last-child td:first-child,
.table-bordered tbody:last-child tr:last-child th:first-child {
    @apply rounded-bl-lg;
}
```